# Django DRY model attributes, classes, and triggers

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm hacking on an graph-based app with about 50 different types of relationships.

They all look like this.

```py
class SomeModel(CustomClazz):
  created_at = DateTimeProperty(default_now=True)
  updated_at = DateTimeProperty(default_now=True)

  class Meta:
    app_label = 'custom_relation'

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.updated_at = datetime.now()
    super(SomeModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

When I started writing this post, I was just looking for a one-liner for `class Meta:` but I realized most of these lines are duplicates for each model.

Although I view the integrity and human-readability of the model as sacred, part of that is keeping my model file short enough that I don't need to split it up into many files.

If the model definition becomes extremely dry, I'd still like to be able to set custom attributes for `SomeModel`.

---

**Q** -- How can I abstract these attributes, subclasses, and functions out of each model?

Comment: `created_at` should have `default_now_add=True`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks, I'll see if that works w this library.

Answer (score 1):

Put the common codes in a mixin and make the mixin a superclass of each model e.g.:

```
class MyMixin:
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'custom_relation'
```

Now:

```
class SomeModel(CustomClazz, MyMixin):
    ...
    ...
```